# Bash history: real life example for & modifiers

Tags: bash, command-history

I am looking learning new tricks in bash command history manipulation, in this page http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifiers.html#Modifiers. I see & modifiers.

when I try !!:& is not recalling previous substitution. Can you help to understand this with real example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First command:

```
$ echo abcdabcd
abcdabcd
```

Replace cd with gf. Note that only the first occurrence is replaced

```
$ !!:s/cd/gf
echo abgfabcd
abgfabcd
```

Repeat the substitution

```
$ !!:&
echo abgfabgf
abgfabgf
```